# How can I capture and store the graphical representation of an html webpage in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm thinking of trying to use javascript's document object in conjunction with getElementbyID and then reference its ContentWindow property, but after that I need some ideas on how to offload the page in the content window into hard storage. My final intention would be to print it out on paper.

Comment: This may help: [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

Comment: Thank you. I've noted this option and it looks promising.

Comment: The way we did this that worked was to create two subdomains of the hosting domain, one for the mapping tool and one for the server on which the IIS app was running. This allowed the iframe to think that the mapper was on its domain and so this opened up the iframe security to allow capture of the image. The next thing was to format the html image using a css script that blocked all page content except for the map so only it was printable-- after that we could open the image in print preview of a browser and we could print it.

Answer (score 0):

The way we did this that worked was to create two subdomains of the hosting domain, one for the mapping tool and one for the server on which the IIS app was running. This allowed the iframe to think that the mapper was on its domain and so this opened up the iframe security to allow capture of the image. The next thing was to format the html image using a css script that blocked all page content except for the map so only it was printable-- after that we could open the image in print preview of a browser and we could print it. – Earl Patrick Dean 12 mins ago